# Linq to select nodes into xml which have node values in list

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have following xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<InstrumentServerData>
 <Node>
   <name>**Test**</name>
   <comments/>
   <DOB/>
   <location/>
   <Configs/>
 </Node>
 <Node>
   <name>**Example**</name>
   <comments/>
   <DOB/>
   <location/>
   <Configs/>
 </Node>
 <Node>
    <name>**Check**</name>
    <comments/>
    <DOB/>
    <location/>
    <Configs/>
 </Node>
```

I have a list 'TestList' which contains 'Test' and 'Check'. I want to select all the entire nodes which have name value in list 'TestList'(i,e filter/delete xml nodes which don't have name value in the list)

Comment: Okay, so have you tried anything yet? Given a `Node` element, you'd want find the `<name>` element with `Element("name")` and then find the text within it - e.g. by casting to `string` (which means you don't need to worry about nodes that don't have a name element...) Please show what you've tried, and what went wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "name value in the list"? You want to delete nodes, where name is empty?

Comment: i want to delete nodes where name tag value does not match my list(TestList) of values(in eg 'Test' and 'Check')